# Calculate something with user defined classes by using variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

struct for coordinates;

```
   struct point{
       int x_, y_;
    }
```

Assume we have a coordinates as it is defined above. In addition to this struct i want to create a function which takes as many parameters as user wants(for instance a function to find the barycentre of three or more points). So i have decided to use variadic templates. But i recognized that i am lack of info about variadic templates.

As to calculate barycentre, you should add all x's, divide the sum to element count. And do it for y's of elements and return a point. Can you lead me a way to implement this.

Comment: Variadic templates sounds wrong in this case. Have you considered a initiliazer_list? It's less generic but still efficient.

Comment: No, i haven't. I can solve this problem with initializer_list but how can we handle it with variadic templates?

Answer (score 2):

C++17's fold-expressions make this a breeze:

```
template <class... Points>
point barycentre(Points... points) {
    point const sum{
        (points.x_ + ...),
        (points.y_ + ...)
    };

    int const num = sizeof...(Points);

    return {
        sum.x_ / num,
        sum.y_ / num
    };
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e9ea77f76daa7df)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++14 you could simply iterate through points in constexpr function, e.g. like this (example borrowed from [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42692165/4324224)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct point{
    int x_, y_;
};

template <class... Points>
constexpr point barycentre(Points... points) {
    point ps[] = {points...};
    point result {0, 0};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(points); i++) {
        result.x_ += ps[i].x_;
        result.y_ += ps[i].y_;
    }
    result.x_ /= sizeof...(points);
    result.y_ /= sizeof...(points);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto bary = barycentre(point{0, 0}, point{2, 2});
    std::cout << "(" << bary.x_ << ", " << bary.y_ << ")\n";
}
```

[[live demo]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac4faff8f20cd8e5)

---

And some C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

struct point{
    int x_, y_;
};

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t N>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<I + 1 == N, point>::type barysum(std::array<point, N> const &points) {
    return point{ points[I].x_, points[I].y_ };
}

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t N>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<I + 1 != N, point>::type barysum(std::array<point, N> const &points) {
    return point{ points[I].x_ + barysum<I+1>(points).x_, points[I].y_ + barysum<I+1>(points).y_ };
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr point barycentre_impl(std::array<point, N> const points_array) {
    return point{ barysum<0>(points_array).x_ / static_cast<int>(N),  barysum<0>(points_array).y_ / static_cast<int>(N)};
}

template <class... Pts>
constexpr point barycentre(Pts... pts) {
    return barycentre_impl<sizeof...(Pts)>( {{pts...}} );
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto bary = barycentre(point{0, 0}, point{2, 2});
    std::cout << "(" << bary.x_ << ", " << bary.y_ << ")\n";
}
```

[[live demo]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49429c57cf072f8c)

Answer (score 1):

Initializer list is simpler for taking elements of the same type.

```
Point average(std::initializer_list<Point> list)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for(auto &i: list) {x += i.x_; y += i.y_;}
    return {x / list.size(), y / list.size()};
}
```

Variadic templates is generic on **types**, so it doesn't fit for your case. It doesn't make your code execute faster in any way, just bloating the binary.